# pandas filter series with lists of strings as values

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to make a simple filter that will take in the dataframe and filter out all rows that don't have the target genre. It'll be easier to explain with the code:

```
    import pandas as pd

test = [{
        "genre":["RPG","Shooter"]},
        {"genre":["RPG"]},
        {"genre":["Shooter"]}]
        
data =pd.DataFrame(test)

fil = data.genre.isin(['RPG'])
```

I want the filter to return a dataframe with the following elements:

```
[{"genre":["RPG"]},
{"genre":["RPG", "Shooter"]}]
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try my code:

```
SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x00000180D1DF2760> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: @Vaishali Is true that the questions are duplicated, but I believe the answers in here are better that the ones provided in the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the elements of genre are lists, so [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) does not work. Use:

```
mask = data['genre'].apply(frozenset(['RPG']).issubset)
print(data[mask])
```

**Output**

```
            genre
0  [RPG, Shooter]
1           [RPG]
```

The expression:

```
frozenset(['RPG']).issubset
```

Checks that any list is contained in each row, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

> Test whether every element in the set is in other.

So you could also check for multiple values easily, for example:

```
mask = data['genre'].apply(frozenset(['RPG', "Shooter"]).issubset)
print(data[mask])
```

**Output**

```
            genre
0  [RPG, Shooter]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
data[data.genre.apply(lambda x: 'RPG' in x)]
```

Or:

```
data[data.genre.explode().eq('RPG').any(level=0)]
```

Output:

```
            genre
0  [RPG, Shooter]
1           [RPG]
```